# Check new inserted data in Postgresql database table in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

How to check or get notified if any new data is inserted into my table using nodejs. I do want to avoid cron.

Is it possible via socket.io ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need a socket or cron to check it. You can use triggers on it.

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ CONSTRAINT ] TRIGGER name { BEFORE | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { event [ OR ... ] }
    ON table_name
    [ FROM referenced_table_name ]
    [ NOT DEFERRABLE | [ DEFERRABLE ] [ INITIALLY IMMEDIATE | INITIALLY DEFERRED ] ]
    [ REFERENCING { { OLD | NEW } TABLE [ AS ] transition_relation_name } [ ... ] ]
    [ FOR [ EACH ] { ROW | STATEMENT } ]
    [ WHEN ( condition ) ]
    EXECUTE { FUNCTION | PROCEDURE } function_name ( arguments )

where event can be one of:

    INSERT
    UPDATE [ OF column_name [, ... ] ]
    DELETE
    TRUNCATE
```

CREATE TRIGGER creates a new trigger. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER will either create a new trigger, or replace an existing trigger. The trigger will be associated with the specified table, view, or foreign table and will execute the specified function function_name when certain operations are performed on that table.

You can create an insert trigger only if you need events at insertion.

Note: Please check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) for more details.

Comment: How I could check it using nodeJs.

Comment: Where are you inserting the data? Are you creating any new scripts to get this information? Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I do need to check if any new data is inserted to my table. If new data is inserted then I do need to send message via NodeJs.

Comment: Why don't you do it where you are inserting the record to the DB? You don't have access to it? It is a bad practice to call scripts from triggers and I won't recommend you. To give efficient solution we might need more information about this ask.

Comment: Insertion is done from DB Process. I dont have that access.